# What does ゆらまひだ mean?

Tags: translation

Google search and dictionaries give me no help, and god knows translators aren't to be trusted.  If you search ゆらまひ in google, images of a certain pair of girls who look like twins come up, does that have anything to do with it?

Context:  It was commented upon a music video, and was the only such comment.

Comment: Welcome to our site!  While not always necessary additional context is always welcome, and can even help you get a better answer.   Would you mind including more context related to where you found this phrase?

Answer (score 2):

”They are ゆらまひ！" "I found that they are ゆらまひ."

or

"They look like ゆらまひ！” "I found them look like ゆらまひ."

or maybe

"(They look alike as though they were twin.) Just like ゆらの＆まひろ."

ゆらまひ＝越智ゆらの（おちゆらの）and 林田真尋(はやしだまひろ）

越智ゆらの is a Japanese fashion model, 18 y.o.

林田真尋 (19) is a Japanese singer and dancer.
(From Wikipedia)

It seems that they often upload their cute *purikura* (Print Club) photos on the web. They look so much alike like a twin. The comment must be something related to them with no doubt.

I haven't encountered the word "ゆらまひ" in my life. If it's a word, it would be an old Japanese word because of the old spelling of "ひ". It should be spelled as ゆらまい in the modern Japanese.

Comment: Oh, so it's a group?  ゆらまひ refers to ゆらの and まひろ?

Comment: If so, does it make sense in your context? :)

Comment: It makes sense in context, but only if the commenter was wrong.

Comment: The commentator might have found some resemblance between the video characters and ゆら＆まひ. For example, the two are very friendly or the two wear the same clothes like a twin do. What was your context?

Comment: After looking up ゆら and まひ, I found a video where they dance to the song(the song that was commented on), and I think that's what was being referred to, but saying what they did is kind of vague.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the input, user25375! So the meaning was: "It's ゆらまひ’s song! (ゆらまひだ！）

Answer (score 2):

> 「ひらまひ」＝「おち **ゆら**の」+「はやしだ **まひ**ろ」

Seesawsceneさんの答えのとおりですね。
I second Seesawscene's answer!

せっかくの機会ですので、私はこの答えを補強するよう情報を提供しようと思います。
It is a great opportunity, so I'll provide some information to reinforce this answer.

これはペアに対する愛称の一つです。特定な用語がないので、以下の説明では、仮に「省略ペア名称」と呼びます。
This is a kind of a nickname for a certain pair of people. Since there is no specific term, in the explanation below, I'm going to call it an "**abbreviated pair's name** or **APN**" temporarily.

実は、省略ペア名称は「ひらまひ」に限らず、「特定のペアの呼称」として日本における言葉遣いのまさに定着しつつある近頃の傾向あるいは流行です。
Actually, APN is not limited to "HiraMahi", but it is a recent tendency of wording in Japan exactly on the way being established as "**addressing/designating a specific pair of people**".

この傾向は「メディア」と日本語で表現される文化の進展とともに登場したように思います。
I think that this trend appeared with the progress of culture expressed as "メディア *≒ media*" in Japanese.

省略ペア名称は、つい最近までは次のような条件が重なったときに使われておりました。作り方は、ペアを構成するメンバー各々の名前（姓名あるいは氏名）の先頭２音節を合成して４音節にして作ります。
Until recently APNs have been made and used when the following conditions overlap. They are made by combining the first two syllables of the name (first or last name of a full name) of each member constituting the pair to make up four syllables

- ペアであること
  Being a pair of people
- 人気があること、あるいは人気を作ろうとするとき
  Being popular; or A promoter or sponser is trying to make the pair's popularity aggressively.
- 少なくとも一方は若い女性であること
  Being a young woman at least one of the pair
- きれいあるいはかわいいこと
  Being pretty or cute

省略ペア名称は、名前の付け方に明確な規則性があるので簡単に作れることとがメリットであり、文字数が少ないので活字メディアの見出し（ヘッドライン）に使うと効果的である点もメリットである。しかし、実際には、二人分の氏名を発音するより簡単に発音できることで、テレビ等での音声で使われるときにより一層効果があるように思う。
It is merit that APN is easy to create because there is clear rule in the way of naming it, and it is also merit that it is effective when used for headlines of printed media such as newspapers because of the small number of characters. However, in fact, it makes it easier to pronounce the name for the two people, so it seems to be even more effective when it is used on a TV broadcast or the like.

あるペアを売り出そうとするプロモータにとって便利な手法だが、まだ市民権を得ていない省略ペア名称に対して一般の人は「勝手な押し売りはよしてくれ」と言いたいこともある。
Although APN is a convenient means for promoters who are planning to make popularity of a pair, we sometimes want to say "No solicitors" to the abbreviated pair name which has not yet popular.

不思議なのは、バドミントンのペアに対してこのAPNは使われるが卓球のペアには何故使われないのだろうか。これは私にはわからない。
It is strange that APN is used for badminton pairs, but why isn't it used for a pair of ping pongs? I cannot explain this.

近頃は女性だけでなくバドミントンのダブルスの男性のペアに対してもこのAPNが使われはじめているので私の定義も怪しいものである。
My definition is doubtful now because APN is starting to be used not only for women but also for badminton men's pair.

Examples of APNs:

- [ゆらまひ](http://www.excite.co.jp/News/entertainment_g/20160915/Ameba_16192.html) Appeared in OP's question. Yuramhi is an APN for Yurano Ochi ([越智]{ochi} ゆらの）and Mahiro Hayashida ([林田]{hayashida} [真尋]{mahiro}）
- [マナカナ](http://www.manakana.jp/) Manakana is an APN for a Japanese twin actresses, talents and  singers of Mana Mikura ([三倉]{mikura} [茉奈]{mana}) and Kana Mikura ([三倉]{mikura} [佳奈]{kana}).
- [オグシオ](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%AA%E3%82%B0%E3%82%B7%E3%82%AA) Ogushio is an APN for a Japanese badminton women's pair of Kumiko Ogura ([小椋]{ogura} [久美子]{kumiko}) and Reiko Shiota ([潮田]{shiota} [玲子]{reiko}).
- [タカマツ](https://mainichi.jp/sportsspecial/articles/20160819/k00/00m/050/205000c) Takamatsu is an APN for a Japanese badminton women's pair of Reika Takahashi ([高橋]{takahashi} [礼華]{reika}) and Matsutomo Misaki ([松友]{matsutomo} [美佐紀]{misaki}).
- [イケシオ](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%A4%E3%82%B1%E3%82%B7%E3%82%AA) Ikeshio is an APN for a Japanese badminton mixed pair of Shintaroh Ikeda ([池田]{ikeda} [信太郎]{shintaroh}) and said Reiko Shiota ([潮田]{shiota} [玲子]{reiko}).
- [ハヤエン](https://matome.naver.jp/odai/2142387363844978201) Hayaen is an APN for a Japanese badminton men's pair of Ken'ichi Hayakawa ([早川]{hayakawa} [賢一]{ken'ichi}) and Hiroyuki Endoh ([遠藤]{endoh} [大由]{hiroyuki})

[image]